# I want to get whatsApp profilepicture but only getting name and contactnumber?

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-contentresolver

I want to get WhatsApp profile picture and number but using contentResolver I will getting only name and number using following snippet code.

```
private void showContactWhatsApp(){

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Cursor contactCursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID},
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
            new String[]{"com.whatsapp"},
            null);


    ArrayList<String> myWhatsappContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    if (contactCursor != null) {
        if (contactCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //whatsappContactId for get Number,Name,Id ect... from  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                    String whatsappContactId = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));

                    if (whatsappContactId != null) {
                        //Get Data from ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone of Specific CONTACT_ID
                        Cursor whatsAppContactCursor = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME},
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{whatsappContactId}, null);

                        if (whatsAppContactCursor != null) {
                            whatsAppContactCursor.moveToFirst();
                            String id = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                            String name = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            String number = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            whatsAppContactCursor.close();

                            //Add Number to ArrayList
                            myWhatsappContacts.add(number);

                            Log.e(TAG, " WhatsApp contact id  :  " + id);
                            Log.e(TAG, " WhatsApp contact name :  " + name);
                            Log.e(TAG, " WhatsApp contact number :  " + number);
                        }
                    }
                } while (contactCursor.moveToNext());
                contactCursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    Log.e(TAG, " WhatsApp contact size :  " + myWhatsappContacts.size());
}
```

I want to get WhatsApp profile picture like SyncMe app.

I wait to get WhatsApp contact list with name, number, and thumbnail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly I just want to reiterate the difference between a `RawContact` and a `Contact`. The latter being an aggregation (representing a person) of the former (representing an account).

Depending on what use you have for the image, it may be better to fetch the aggregate Contact and use the Profile image selected there which can be achieved via the [Photo contract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html).

```
Uri photoUri;
Cursor photoCur = cr.query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + aggregateContactId + " AND " + 
    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", 
    null, null
);
if (photoCur != null && photoCur.moveToFirst()) {
    Uri photoId = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, aggregateContactId);
    photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
}
```

If you have use specifically for the WhatsApp photo, first make sure the photo is cached on the device (just to avoid false flags while testing - open the contacts full image in WhatsApp and you can be sure it's cached) then you'll have to do a separate lookup for the image (from API 14):

```
Uri photoId = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, whatsappContactId);
Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(photoId, RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

Comment: how to get aggregateContactId here ?